# Is Cloud Firestore API using some network security protocol?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore with an Android app. I understand that once on the server-side data are encrypted as per https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/server-side-encryption. However, I am wondering if Firestore API (especially for Android) comes with a network security protocol by default or do we have to take care of that in order to encrypt client-to-server transmission?

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 2):

All data from and to Cloud Firestore goes over HTTP**S** connections, so it's encrypted on the transport layer (known as [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)).

This applies to the SDKs that Firebase provides, but also to the REST API. There is no unsecured way to get data into (or from) Cloud Firestore.

Comment: What version of TLS though? 1.0+?